# Graph transformation - vertices into edges and edges into vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph

is there any algorithm or is there any name for a transformation of a graph where one can transform edges into vertices and vertices into edges? Just so we could get a new graph out of it or anything similiar to this problem? I'm not sure if it actually makes sense but I'd be glad if you could give me just any hint about a problem like this.

Comment: Where would you like the new edges? Where the old edges meet at a vertex? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_graph

Comment: Seems to me like any transformation of this type would be exponential in time, since it could be used to reduce the hamilton cycle problem to the Euler cycle problem.

Comment: @jan-dvorak Yes, Edge graph is what I was looking for, thanks. So now I know how to transform a directed graph into its directed line graph, but do you know if there is a way to transform it back to an origial graph?

Comment: @krajol see the wikipedia article. You need to find a way to cover the line graph with cliques (complete subgraph) such that every vertex is a part of two cliques.

Comment: If you only connect inedges to outedges you need to find the covering with the corresponding graphs (complete bipartite). This particular case might be easier than the undirected case: all inedges to a vertex in the line graph belong to one complete bipartite subgraph, all outedges belong to the other incident complete bipartite.

Comment: @ImreKerr It does not necessarily, right? Because number of vertices in the graph will not be equal to number of edges in the the equivalent line graph/ edge graph. Think about a star graph with 1 centre vertex and 3 adjacent vertices (comprising of 3 edges). The corresponding edge graph will just be a triangle with 3 vertices. So one can't make the correspondence.

Answer (score 4):

LineGraph is a built-in function in Wolfram Language:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineGraph.html

This is what it does:

- Each vertex in LineGraph[g] corresponds to an edge in g.
- For an undirected graph g, two vertices in LineGraph[g] are adjacent if their corresponding edges share a common vertex.
- For a directed graph g, two vertices in LineGraph[g] are adjacent if their corresponding edges are connected, i.e. the target of one edge is the source of the other edge.
- LineGraph works with undirected graphs, directed graphs, and multigraphs.

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about **pattern-based graph transformation**? Like that you would

- search for a graph pattern, e.g. the kind of edge that you'd like to turn into a node, and
- define the operation of transforming that edge into a node/vertex, e.g. transferring all the edge properties into properties of the new node/vertex.

In graph transformation literature, these two steps are called *left-hand side* and *right-hand side* of a **graph-transformation-rule**.

There is a lot of scientific literature available in that field, e.g.: http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783319211442

There are also specialized development solutions for graph transformation, like [Soley Studio](https://www.soley.io/en/pr-soley-studio/).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is a line graph. You can use the [networkx line_graph function](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.line.line_graph.html) to create a line graph or dual graph of a given graph. However, note that this function does not propagate the data from the original graph so you will have to hack your way around that if you need it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you could easily turn the edges into vertices using the following Python library: http://networkx.lanl.gov/

You can get the edge list, the nodes list and exchange the two for building a new graph. You just need some (basic) knowledge of Python.

Comment: 1. I think the link is wrong. I think you meant the networkx library. it is library for graphs... 
2. networkx has build-in function for it "line_graph"...